# OpencvSharp ver 2.4.8.20140523 (Any CPU build) not supported in mono for android

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

I am working on Xamarin Android project which requires some image processing.
I tried integrating the latest(Any CPU build) version of OpenCVSharp in to my Xamarin.Android project. The home page of [OpenCvsharp Github](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/) says OpenCVsharp can run on any platform which supports mono. But when the assemblies are loaded on compilation, it is returning a FileNotFoundException- "Could not load assembly System.Drawing. What is the work around to get it working in mono for android ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Me too have same issue "Could not load assembly System.Drawing".. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV requires `System.Drawing`, and in turn is dependent of GDI+. Thus, it only supports full CLR profile, such as .NET Framework from Microsoft or full Mono on Mac OS X and Linux, where GDI+ is available.

For Xamarin.Android, or any other CLR profiles that lack of GDI+, you have to use alternatives, such as Android native image support,

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3aAndroid.Graphics

Comment: So it means I will need to hack in to the library and change the current references to each method/property calls to the corresponding ones in Android.Graphics counterparts right ?

Comment: You might hack it in that direction, but I personally think the effort can be huge. Good luck.